# KDE: Nice overlay when using keyboard hotkeys

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde

in Ubuntu Gnome, I get a nice overlay when

- Adjusting Keyboard backlight
- Enable Airplane mode
- disable Bluetooth
- Adjust volume (this one works in Kubuntu, too)
- Adjust brightness (this one worksd in Kubuntu, too)

All those hot keys also works in **Kubuntu**, too, but there is no overlay for the first three. I wonder if one could port this from Ubuntu to Kubuntu.

Googling is a bit complicated, as I don't know how this feature is correctly called.

Does anyone know a solution?

**Edit**: I reported this as a KDE bug, it's already assigned to a developer: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=415462